# How to write a long string literal in which no characters are escaped?

Tags: javascript

I have a script (in another language) that generates pieces of valid JavaScript which is then executed in the browser. The generated javascript looks e.g. like this:

```
my_function(123,"long string with lots of weird characters");
```

That "long string" can potentially contain quotes, apostrophes, backslashes etc... For example the "long string" can be any of these:

```
hello"there
hello'there
hello\\\\"\\\'\'\\\'"'\"\\"""there
```

All these characters should be passed as they are to my_function(), without assuming that backslash is a special character that escapes something.

Does javascript have some sort of unique "tag" to delimit a long string literal in which nothing should be "escaped" or "interpreted"? For example a construct similar to this:

```
my_function(123, [<STRING_START>]long string with lots of weird characters[<STRING_END>]);
```

I need something like this and I can guarantee that my long string won't contain the string "][<STRING_END>]" so this would work. However I cannot easily guarantee that it won't contain quotes and/or backslashes.

I know that I can use e.g. the normal quotes to delimit my string and programmaticaly add backslashes (in my javascript generator) before all required characters inside the string but the existence of "tags" shown above (or something similar) would make the life easier for me.

Comment: Well, any character that is used to signify the end of the string would need to be escaped inside the string. There is the `String.raw` tagged template (`String.raw\`\try this\``), but you'd still have to escape backticks inside the value itself.

Comment: That's why I was asking about multi-byte start/end tag. I can guarantee fairly easily it won't be present in my string.

Comment: That doesn't exist. The only "string" delimiters are `'`, `"` and `\``.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **String.raw** :

> It's used to get the raw string form of template literals, that is,
> substitutions (e.g. ${foo}) are processed, but escapes (e.g. \n) are
> not.

```
var hello= String.raw` there
hello'there
hello\\\\"\\\'\'\\\'"'\"\\"""there `;
```